# How do I login in a App page and direct the page to Home?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

UPDATE

Guys, you have helped me to solve part of the issue.

The new issue now is that, when I do the login in the App, it appears wrong for me like below:

[image: Home Screen Wrong]

And it has to appear in the right way what is represented below:

[image: Home Screen Right]

I've looked forward in the code and I think it could be some issue in App.js at the following snippet:

```
return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Fragment>
            <LoadingBar style={{ zIndex: 1000 }} />
            <Menu />
            <div className='ui main text container' style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  path='/'
                  exact
                  render={() => {
                    return (
                      <QuestionList
                        handleTabChange={this.handleTabChange}
                        activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
                       />
                    )
                  }}
                 />
```

But I haven't figured out what could it be the problem. I've tried to search something here in stackoverflow and I haven't obtained success.

I've modified in codesandbox for the same way is for me now. Please check there and I'd appreciate any help:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sammet-iincf

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Because you didn't add `<Route path='/login' component={xxxx} />` in the `<Switch>`.

Comment: Inside App.js, @LeonF ?

Comment: @LeonF, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App.js you had the following routes defined for when the user is logged in:

```
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            render={...}
          />
          <Route
            path="/add"
            render={...}
          />
          <Route path="/questions/:question_id" component={QuestionView} />
          <Route path="/leaderboard" component={Leaderboard} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
          <Route path="/404" component={PageNotFound} />
          <Route path="/" component={PageNotFound} />`
```

Notice that there is no "/login" route defined for when a user is logged in. This is why you're getting the PageNotFound error. Also you've defined the "/" route twice, so you'll want to remove the second definition.

Comment: Hi, @pskfry. I've looked closely to the code, and if you notice the '/login' is a step before this one you indicated (look ```if (!authedUser) { return (...<Route path='/' component={Login}....)). So I understand that the path '/login' appears. You have reason that the '/' route is defined twice, thus I deleted it. But it appeared other issue to me. I'll edit the question above and show you what happens now.

Comment: Add this line:

```history.push("/");```

to the end of handleUserLogin() in Login component. The problem is you're authorizing the user but you're never pushing a new route for them after you're authenticating them. So they're staying on /Login.

You can also do this by setting a loggedIn state to true and rendering a <Redirect to="/" /> in your render function if this.state.loggedIn is true. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the referrer block at the bottom of handleUserLogin() but it doesn't really seem necessary.